# Java - create prn.json file on disk

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to create a blank file with name PRN.json. For some reason createNewFile() didn't create it and no exception was thrown. When I tried manually to create a file with same name I got 'The specified device name is invalid'. Any thoughts?

System: Windows 8, Java 1.8, 64 bit OS

```
Java Code
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestJson
{
public static void main( String[] args )
    {   
        try {

          boolean bool = false;
          File file = new File("C:\\Data\\PRN.json");

           bool = file.createNewFile();

           System.out.println("File Exists "+bool);

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have writing permissions in `C:\Data`?

Comment: Oh yes. I have. I'm able to create PRN1.json not PRN.json

Comment: You're able to programmatically create PRN1.json?? Is there already a file named PRN.json?

Comment: I figured it out. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS#Reserved_device_names

Comment: Ohhh. Answer your own question then!

Comment: Googling results:PRN is a reserved device names in DOS and it cannot be used as file name regardless of extension as they are occupied by built-in character devices.
Please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS#Reserved_device_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRN apparently is an alias for Windows to a local print device. Try a different filename.